# MySQL query to get data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to select a conversation_id from a MySQL table where the users in a conversation is the exact match of users provided in an array such as (2, 5) - which should return 1 as the conversation id.

Extract of the db table as follows:

```
user_ids (2, 5)

conversation_users:

conversation_id      user_id
1                    2
1                    5
2                    2
2                    6
```

Can this be done in a single query?

**EDIT - 26.06.2014**

Actually, after doing some testing this does not always work correctly. If there are more users that belong to a conversation than there are in the array, it will still return all the conversations those users belong to.

I would like to get an exact match of users in the array to users in the conversation.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c82d/1)

In the example below, conversations 6 and 7 are both returned but it should not return any rows:

```
SELECT `conversation_id` FROM `conversation_user` WHERE `user_id` IN (70, 426)
GROUP BY `conversation_id` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) = 2;


conversation_user_id  conversation_id user_id
14                    6               70
15                    6               29
16                    6               442
17                    6               425
18                    6               426
19                    7               70
20                    7               442
21                    7               426
22                    7               499
23                    7               425
24                    7               29
```

Comment: Similar answer from today http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d856b/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible by using a combination of `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` clauses, like this:

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM conversation_users
WHERE user_id IN (2,5)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2
```

**2nd Option**:

In case, there are more than two records (users) in one conversation then you have couple of alternatives. One option is given below, in which `WHERE` clause is removed and `GROUP_CONCAT`  is used, like this:

```
SELECT `conversation_id` FROM `conversation_user` 
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) = 2
AND GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user_id` ORDER BY `user_id` ASC SEPARATOR ',') = '70,426'
```

However, this may not be a very flexible approach because it expects the user list to be a sorted comma-separated string.

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c82d/13

**3rd Option**:

Instead of `GROUP_CONCAT` (as in the 2nd option above), use a sub-query to get only those conversations which have only 2 users. Then join this sub-query with the main table and apply the same filter (`WHERE` and `GROUP BY`) as used in the 1st option given above, like this:

```
SELECT `conversation_id` 
FROM `conversation_user` 
JOIN (
  SELECT `conversation_id` t_cid FROM `conversation_user` 
  GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) = 2
) t
ON t.t_cid = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id`
WHERE `user_id` IN (70, 426)
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) = 2
```

Should be a better approach because it does not rely on the sorted comma-separated list required in the 2nd option.

**Working Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c82d/21

Comment: Is the value of "2" in `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2` the count of number of users in the array?

Comment: @AsaCarter yes, you are correct. The value "2" is the number of users in the array.

Comment: Edited question above. The answer is not working correctly when there a more users in the conversation.

Comment: @AsaCarter Based on your edits, I have updated my answer above.